# How to restore scroll position of the GridView when navigating back Visual Basic

Tags: c#, vb.net, gridview, windows-store-apps

I want to restore the scroll position when navigating back, I have found [a C# code](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/priozersk/archive/2012/09/09/how-to-restore-scroll-position-of-the-gridview-when-navigating-back.aspx) and tried to convert in to Visual Basic and currently is giving me lots of errors.

C# code:

```
void ItemsPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   this.gridScrollViewer = FindVisualChild<ScrollViewer>(this.itemGridView);
   this.gridScrollViewer.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(App.ScrollOffset);
}

protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
   App.ScrollOffset = gridScrollViewer.HorizontalOffset;
   base.OnNavigatedFrom(e);
}
```

And my converted VB code:

```
Private Sub ItemsPage_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    Me.gridScrollViewer = FindVisualChild(Of ScrollViewer)(Me.itemGridView)
    Me.gridScrollViewer.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(App.ScrollOffset)
End Sub
Protected Overrides Sub OnNavigatedFrom(e As NavigationEventArgs)
    App.ScrollOffset = gridScrollViewer.HorizontalOffset

    MyBase.OnNavigatedFrom(e)
End Sub
```

Errors:

[image]

Comment: Did you rename the variables to what yours are? Did you implement `FindVisualChild(...)`? I also don't see `Handles` on your event methods.

Comment: @TyCobb +1. C# and VB.net declare events differently. See this [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/edzehd2t(v=vs.110).aspx) about raising events. I suggest you generate the events by selecting the event from the drop-down in the editor.

Comment: Unfortunately i can't access my xaml gridview as it is inside of the datatemplate. How can i implement `FindVisualChild(...)`

Comment: `FindVisualChild` is implemented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613579.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-4)

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem few months ago. Your method:

```
FindVisualChild<ScrollViewer>()
```

You can implement this way (You can rewrite it to VB.Net i do not have lot time to rewrite it).

```
 public static T GetVisualChild<T>(DependencyObject parent) where T : DependencyObject
        {
            T child = default(T);
            int numVisuals = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
            for (int i = 0; i < numVisuals; i++)
            {
                DependencyObject v = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
                child = v as T;
                if (child == null)
                    child = GetVisualChild<T>(v);
                if (child != null)
                    break;
            }
            return child;
        }
```

Then you can call it as you wrote:

```
 var gridScrollViewer = (ScrollViewer)Helpers.GetVisualChild<ScrollViewer>(this.itemGridView);
 if (gridScrollViewer != null)
{
        gridScrollViewer.ChangeView(App.ScrollOffset, null, null, true);
       //this is not supported in next windows releases after Win8.1
       //Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ScrollViewer.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(double)' is obsolete: 'ScrollToHorizontalOffset may be altered or unavailable for releases after Windows 8.1. Instead, use ChangeView.
       // gridScrollViewer.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(App.ScrollOffset);
}
```

To acces your grid by name you have to add name to grid in xaml.

```
 <GridView
            x:Name="itemGridView"
```

I hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

VB Variant of implementation:

```
Public Shared Function GetVisualChild(Of T As DependencyObject)(ByVal parent As DependencyObject) As T
        Dim visualChild As T = Nothing
        Dim childrenCount As Int32 = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent)
        Dim num As Int32 = 0
        While num < childrenCount
            Dim child As DependencyObject = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, num)
            visualChild = DirectCast((TryCast(child, T)), T)
            If (visualChild Is Nothing) Then
                visualChild = Helpers.GetVisualChild(Of T)(child)
            End If
            If (visualChild Is Nothing) Then
                num = num + 1
            Else
                Exit While
            End If
        End While
        Return visualChild
    End Function
```